# White border on iOS when orientation is Landscape

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, maui

in my .NET MAUI App I have a background image which is displayed in full screen width, when orientation is Portrait. But when I change orientation to Landscape, I can see a white Frame/Border. I am running this on iOS Simulator right now.

Well, on a real iPhone Xs there is this the front camera which takes a little space. So, when I turn my iPhone and orientation is Landscape, I would expect this space on that side as well. But on the opposite site?

Question is as well, if there is a possibility to get my background image to full width, even if there is a little space for the camera. I definitively want to get rid of this white space there.

It also looks strange on the side where the Flyout is right now.

Is there a possibility?

**Portrait View**

[image]

**Landscape View**

[image]

============ Regarding Comment - Code of my AppShell ==============

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Shell
    x:Class="OptimizerApp.AppShell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:OptimizerApp.Pages"
    xmlns:loc="clr-namespace:LocalizationResourceManager.Maui;assembly=LocalizationResourceManager.Maui"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:OptimizerApp"
    Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Flyout">

    
    <Shell.FlyoutHeader>
        <Grid HeightRequest="150">
            <Image Source="1.png" Aspect="AspectFill"/>
        </Grid>
    </Shell.FlyoutHeader>

    
    
    <FlyoutItem Icon="2.png" Title="{loc:Translate Flyout_Home}" FlyoutDisplayOptions="AsSingleItem">
        <ShellContent Icon="2.png" Title="{loc:Translate AppShell_Home}" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate pages:MainPage}" Route="MainPage" Shell.PresentationMode="Animated" />
    </FlyoutItem>

    <FlyoutItem FlyoutIcon="3.png" Title="{loc:Translate Flyout_Settings}" FlyoutDisplayOptions="AsSingleItem">
        <ShellContent Icon="3.png" Title="{loc:Translate Flyout_Settings}" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate pages:Settings}" Route="Settings" Shell.PresentationMode="Animated" />
    </FlyoutItem>

    <FlyoutItem FlyoutIcon="4.png" Title="{loc:Translate Flyout_Help}" FlyoutDisplayOptions="AsSingleItem">
        <ShellContent Icon="4.png" Title="{loc:Translate Flyout_Help}" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate pages:Help}" Route="Help" Shell.PresentationMode="Animated" IsVisible="True"/>
    </FlyoutItem>
    
    

    <Shell.FlyoutFooter>
        <Grid HeightRequest="60" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Gray900}">
            <Label TextColor="White" Text="{loc:Translate Copyright}" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Grid.Row="0"/>
        </Grid>
    </Shell.FlyoutFooter>

</Shell>
```

Comment: Are you using `Shell` in your app? Please help add the XAML code to your post which may be helpful to reproduce the issue. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I am using Shell - I added the code of AppShell.xaml for that

Comment: Consider setting `Shell.NavBarIsVisible="false"` in your `Shell` which can get rid of the extra space when your iPhone Xs is in Portrait.

Comment: Well, honestly, I want to see the NavBar, but I also tried this and it did not remove the white frame on the right and left :(

Comment: This looks like a known issue: [Image AspectFill not working
#6378](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/6378), you can follow up there or open a new one if needed.